# Discord Bot python understanding

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to understand some basics in the making of a discord bot

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

client.run(TOKEN
```

I didn’t understand clearly what the  `@client.event` does and how it works, I know its some kind of listener and the function `get_ready` Is it a function built in the discord.py package bcz apparently its the same name everywhere

Comment: briefly: discord runs loop which periodically gets message (event) from server (or from some of your own functions) - and it has dictionary with functions assigned to different events. `{"event_on_ready": function_on_ready,...}` and when it gets message `event_ready` then it checks this message in dictionary to see which function to execute. And you use `@client.event` to add your function to this dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @client.event is a listener. When discord realises that event has occured it will callback this function.

The name `on_ready` is the sam everywhere because it only makes sense to use it. No, you don’t need to use on_ready, you can use anything else but you just need to specify it in the decorator instead.

By default, if you just do @client.event, it will take the name of your function.

```py
@client.event(‘on_ready’)
def anotherfuncname():
   …
```

Comment: Yeah ok got it , and one other thing, I understood the concept behind asynchronous functions, it means that lets say all the steps in the function will be working at the same time, we don’t need to finish executing a line to be able to execute the line after, but the thing I want to clarify is the uses of the function `await` , when we should place it, is it when we expect some command to take time to return a response we place the await with it to tell a python in a way “okay you can skip this line but remember there’s a response that you should wait for before finishing executing the fct?

Comment: @Jcode you can use `await func()` only with function which was defined as `async def func():`. Not all functions can be used with `await`. For example you can't use `await time.sleep()` but there is special `asyncio.sleep()`. `await func()` means - this `func()` needs time to get result so you can jump to other async functions and later you can check if `func()` already gets result and continue in next line.  async doesn't have to run all functions at the same time but only jump from one function to another when it see `await`